# Problem with 'do' method in old version of Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently working with Rails 5.0.7.2 and ruby 2.4.10p364 for learning purposes.
I'm still a newbie. I have an embedded index.html file using Postgres. It seems to me that it's just a typing error in the script itself, but I can't confirm. Everything I try to do, It keeps returning me the "undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass" error.
So far, I've tried to modify the embedding style, but it keeps giving the me Exception in Action Controller error thing just right after the header.

```
<h1>Portfolio Items</h1>

  <% @porfolio_items.each do |portfolio_item| %>
    <p><%= portfolio_item.title %></p>
    <p><%= portfolio_item.subtitle %></p>
    <p><%= portfolio_item.body %></p>
    <%= image_tag portfolio_item.thumb_image %>
  
<% end %>
```

This is the controller.

```
class PortfoliosController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @portfolio_items = Portfolio.all
  end
end
```

I've even tried to add a "<% if @portfolio_items %>" separate line of code, but to no avail.
Any help would be appreciated. Is this a version thing or is there something I'm not looking at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `@porfolio_items` is nil. You have a typo there, a missing "T", it's not the same the instance variable from the index action.

Comment: Wow. Appreciate you waking me up from my nonsense. I guess I haven't been sleeping much lately lol. Literally been going for hours on this. Thanks